# How do I migrate an old, answered question to another SE site?

Tags: support, migrated-questions

A long time ago, I [answered a question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1645190/22674). The answer I wrote was somewhat well received, but it would serve the audience at [security.stackexchange.com](https://security.stackexchange.com/) better. However, at the time, `security.stackexchange.com` did not yet exist.

Is it possible to still migrate the question + answers to security.stackexchange.com?

Comment: Questions older than 60 days are blocked from being migrated.  CMs can migrate older content if necessary but it's rare to happen.

Comment: Tbh, this sort of question is needed on SO as well. Just look at all of the questions with massive security flaws.

Answer (score 4):

A question that is older than 60 days cannot<sup>*</sup> be migrated to another Stack Exchange site. Other sites have previously requested that Stack Overflow not use them as dumping grounds for old content that it no longer wants. It gets in the way of the process of community-building that all sites must go through as they establish their own niche.

Additionally, it must be pointed out that the existence of another site with an overlapping topic area does not change the status of questions about that topic on Stack Overflow. That is a really confusing way of saying that, just because there is a specialized site devoted to security issues, security issues as relate specifically to programming are still on-topic for Stack Overflow. Those questions need not be closed or migrated away. They are *just fine* here. I agree with Ben—this question is perfectly legitimate for Stack Overflow and has a place here. Many programmers do not know this information and would be well-served to use it as a resource.

If you think a *similar* resource would be useful on the Security site, and it does not already exist, then you could ask a new question on that site. You could even self-answer if you wanted. Opening a new question seems sort of redundant, but the idea behind it is that it allows the content of the answers to be specifically tailored to the community. On Stack Overflow, answers would need to relate specifically to programming, whereas on Security, they can be more broad.

<sub><sup>*</sup> That is, except by [community managers](https://stackoverflow.com/company/team#Community), individuals who are employed by Stack Overflow, Inc. and can perform certain "super-moderator" tasks. A custom moderator flag would be the traditional way to get their attention, or perhaps a Meta post in cases where you want to open the issue up for community discussion. The community managers would want to get clearance from the *target* site as well, before initiating the migration, so it might be more appropriate to ask the question on the proposed target site's Meta: *"Hey Security folks, do we want this old question from Stack Overflow about salt generation? I think it would be an asset to our community because…"*</sub>