# Can we please move all vim questions to vi.stackexchange.com?

Tags: discussion, support, tags, migration

There exists a Stackexchange dedicated to `vi` and `vim` https://vi.stackexchange.com/.

Most of the questions on `vi` and `vim` on stackoverflow are **significantly** more on-topic on https://vi.stackexchange.com/.

**Can we please move all (or most) of the Stackoverflow.com questions tagged with `vi` or `vim` to https://vi.stackexchange.com/ ?**

Comment: _"improve vi.stackexchange.com by improving it's foundation and improving it's google search rankings"_ And artificially grow the community, which the team is very much not happy to do. Add to that what yivi said, and I don't think this is a good idea.

Comment: You'd better consider the health of that site.  It only got 4 questions today and they got only 1 answer.  Its meta site doesn't even have a valid https certificate anymore.  Nobody noticed, nothing posted there for months.  That is a dead site, the company doesn't retire them anymore.  You'll have to play this through that meta site first to see if they want them, don't expect a quick response :)

Comment: Related: [Is it appropriate to post vim questions on Stack Overflow now that there is a vi/vim site?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/287089/7795130)

Comment: What Vim question have you encountered that was blatantly off topic recently?

Comment: I'd worry less about where the questions live in and more about the content being duplicated across multiple sites.

Comment: Questions over 60 days old cannot be migrated ...

Comment: did you ask vi site folks at their meta, what do they think about this idea?

Comment: re "60 days" yes that is what the "duplicate question link said". i think that pretty much settles the issue as not really technically possible.

Comment: @gnat re "did i ask on vi site": no i thought the owners were here so i would ask here. but i think the question has been settled here. so it's not worth asking on the vi site. (settled by https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/318026/52074 and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/287089/52074).

Comment: @rene re "[i noticed how you have lots of point] both here and on the target site": [your comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/375552/can-we-please-move-all-vim-questions-to-vi-stackexchange-com?noredirect=1#comment639813_375552) feels to me like a "subtle put-downs" because you are insinuating that I am trying to somehow gain lots of points... your comment feels to me like a ["personal attacks" instead of "focusing on my question" you are "focusing on my person."](https://stackoverflow.com/conduct). Your comment doesn't feel patient/welcoming/kind/friendly.

Comment: @HansPassant "nothing posted there for months. That is a dead site": i just went to the vi site... there are 6 questions active within the last 24 hours. and there is 86% answered rate. and 5,195 visits per day. all those numbers don't seem like a dead site to me. but definitely won't be a fast turnaround like stackoverflow.com

Comment: @rene "[i noticed how you have lots of points]... on the target site": I went to visit site. I have 137 points on vi site. 100 of which are granted automatically. So 37 points. On stackoverflow.com I don't even know how to check my points per tag but I saw I have 5 questions from him tag with not that many votes... so again not that many tags. --> given my small number of points in both sites... it makes your comment feel to me even more like a "subtle put-down and focusing on the person instead of content" which is what the stackoverflow.com/conduct is trying to discourage.

Comment: @TrevorBoydSmith if you feel that way certainly flag it.  I did my research and left my comment because I was wondering what motivated you to request this as your question is nothing more then *Move these questions*. I had hoped my comment would inspire you to add extra arguments and examples which questions would have worked better on VI.se. It doesn't look like it will not go that way.  Too bad. For the record, my comment mentioned *contributions* not *lots of points*. I've deleted the offending comment. I'm sorry.

Comment: @rene i'm glad to hear your comment was well intentioned after all. i appreciate your help! and contributions! stackexchange has done a lot of good over the years IMO. ||| regarding "add extra arguments and examples" i chose not to provide more answers. i chose not to provide additional information because of the overwhelming response (duplicate question, yivi's response, the linked to question in the comments, 20+ downvotes). the response persuaded me to change my mind.

Comment: @HansPassant re "Its meta site doesn't even have a valid https certificate anymore" if you go to https://vi.meta.stackexchange.com/ my chrome browser says the cert is valid. if you go to https://meta.vi.stackexchange.com/ my chrome browser says the cert is bad `NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID`. perhaps you went to the wrong url.

Answer (score 19):

- That a question is on-topic somewhere else doesn't mean that a question is off-topic here.
- The fact that a question is tagged vi is not even a guarantee that the question would be fit and on-topic in vi.se.
- You would be taking away reputation from existing users here, who may not agree to have their questions migrated.

Nay from me.