# Why do we have a tag Arduino and Raspberry Pi if we have special SE sites for that?

Tags: discussion, tags

We have SE sites specialized on [Arduino](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/) and [Raspberry Pi](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/). Why should we have these tags here?Why not to migrate all questions about Arduino and Raspberry Pi there?
You can get an answer more faster there. Or maybe these tags on SO for special questions about programming?

Comment: Questions for those devices can still be valid on Stack Overflow even with those sites in operation. In general it is possible for a question to be valid on multiple sites but it is discouraged from cross posting the question on multiple sites.

Comment: Related: [Can we please move all vim questions to vi.stackexchange.com?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/375552/7795130)

Comment: The number of eyes that see things posted on SO is orders of magnitude higher than the eyes that would see questions on either one of those sites. And, I suspect, the people asking the questions are fortunate to have found SO and don't have a clue about the other sites.

Comment: *"You can get an answer more faster there."* - hmm, I don't think so. You may get a really dedicated answer a little quicker, maybe. The really hard to write kind, I can see how on a dedicated site you have a higher chance of a topic expert to write a really comprehensive answer if you are lucky enough that those experts want to make the dedicated site a big success and thus patrol it regularly.

Comment: _"New contributor"_...? Pretty sure I've seen you before. Same nick, same avatar, etc...?

Comment: @yivi I recreated my profile as I got blocked from asking questions.

Comment: Deletion and recreation generally doesn't lift the ban; you're still going to encounter difficulties while posting.  They might be slightly looser than they were, but they're still there.

Comment: @fbueckert Well, I'll try to do my best not to get blocked again.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are two very distinct reasons for this.

1. Stack Overflow existed *well* before either of those network sites did.  Those who actually do programming work on an Arduino or Raspberry Pi are perfectly comfortable asking their questions here, and we're perfectly comfortable with answering them.
2. A programming question involving either Arduino or Raspberry Pi here is **not** off-topic.  We welcome programming questions.  What we don't discuss *here* is the hardware aspect of working with these boards.

Migrating these questions wouldn't do any good, since we don't migrate questions older than 60 days *anywhere* at all (it is technically a hurdle to do it - only employees could and they generally *don't*), and there's no guarantee that the questions we're migrating would actually get the attention they need to begin with.  Best to leave 'em here.

Answer (score 3):

Just because there are SE-sites that specialize on them doesn't mean that they should be migrated since they are single-board microcontrollers that can be programmed and programming related questions are definitly suitable for SO.

From the help center:

> What topics can I ask about here?
>   Stack Overflow is for professional and enthusiast programmers, people who write code because they love it. We feel the best Stack Overflow questions have a bit of source code in them, but if your question generally covers…
>
> - a specific programming problem, or
> - a software algorithm, or
> - software tools commonly used by programmers; and is
> - a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development